# How to encode a string when sent via WebBluetooth

Tags: c, arduino, bluetooth, web-bluetooth

I'm quite new to using WebBluetooth and Arduino. I want to create a PWA which acts as a barcode reader. But in comparison to other Apps, I would like to send the discovered code via WebBluetooth to a dongle that should emulate a keyboard. My dongle is based on an Arduino Leonardo and HM-10 bluetooth module.

My Arduino sketch is:

```
// include keyboard
#include <Keyboard.h>

// include softserial
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

// set pins
const int bluetooth_rx_pin = 10;
const int bluetooth_tx_pin = 11;

const int led_blue = 0;
const int led_green = 1;
const int led_red = 2;
const int led_yellow = 3;

// configure connection to bluetooth module as SoftwareSerial
SoftwareSerial SerialBT(bluetooth_rx_pin, bluetooth_tx_pin);

String input;

void setup() {
  // establish connection to bluetooth module
  SerialBT.begin(9600);
  
  // start keyboard functionality
  Keyboard.begin();

  // set pin mode for LEDs
  pinMode(led_blue, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led_green, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led_red, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led_yellow, OUTPUT);

  // switch on blue LED to show finished setup
  digitalWrite(led_blue, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  // switch red off an green on to show that the device is ready to recieve data via bluetooth
  digitalWrite(led_green, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(led_red, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led_yellow, LOW);

  // check availability of bluetooth data
  if (SerialBT.available()){
    // switch off green led, switch on red led
    digitalWrite(led_green, LOW);
    digitalWrite(led_red, HIGH);

    // get data from bluetooth serial
    input = SerialBT.readString();

    // print the string
    Keyboard.print(input);

    // switch yellow LED on
    digitalWrite(led_yellow, HIGH);
    
    // send success message
    SerialBT.println("OK");
  }
}
```

My JavaScript for establishing the connection is:

```
var myCharacteristic;

var deviceName;

var bluetoothConnected = false;

function bluetoothConnect() {
    let serviceUuid = "0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";

    let characteristicUuid = "0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";

    navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({filters: [{services: [serviceUuid]}]})
        .then(device => {
            log('Connecting...');
            deviceName = device.name;
            return device.gatt.connect();
        })
        .then(server => {
            console.log('Getting Service...');
            return server.getPrimaryService(serviceUuid);
        })
        .then(service => {
            console.log('Getting Characteristic...');
            return service.getCharacteristic(characteristicUuid);
        })
        .then(characteristic => {
            myCharacteristic = characteristic;
            return myCharacteristic.startNotifications().then(_ => {
                console.log('> Notifications started');
                log("Connected to: " + deviceName);
                bluetoothConnected = true;
                showContentContainer();
                setBluetoothDeviceName(deviceName);
                myCharacteristic.addEventListener('characteristicvaluechanged',
                    handleNotifications);
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Argh! ' + error);
        });
}

function bluetoothDisconnect() {
    if (myCharacteristic) {
        myCharacteristic.stopNotifications()
            .then(_ => {
                console.log('> Notifications stopped');
                log("Disconnected")
                myCharacteristic.removeEventListener('characteristicvaluechanged',
                    handleNotifications);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('Argh! ' + error);
            });
    }
}

function handleNotifications(event) {
    let value = event.target.value;
    log(deviceName + "> " + new TextDecoder().decode(value));
}

function bluetoothSend(text) {
    log("You> " + text);
    myCharacteristic.writeValue(str2ab(text+"\n"))
}

function str2ab(str) {
    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length*2); // 2 bytes for each char
    var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
    for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i<strLen; i++) {
        bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return buf;
}

function log(str) {
    console.log(str);
}
```

I used as a template https://github.com/hewittwill/WebBluetooth-Terminal/blob/master/index.html

Now, I only get the first letter typed in. If I add console output and view it in the terminal, everything looks good. I already tried to split the string up into a char array on the arduino, and send each char separately. This lead to complete random other chars typed in. So, I assume that the Arduino cannot decode the String recieved via bluetooth correctly.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The code in `str2ab()` converts the string to an `ArrayBuffer` encoded with UTF-16. A string like "Hi!" becomes `{72, 0, 105, 0, 33, 0}`. The Arduino libraries typically expect UTF-8 (or more likely, ASCII) and so they interpret those zeros as the end of the string rather than as the high-order byte of a 16-bit character.

In addition to the `TextDecoder` you use to convert `ArrayBuffer`s received from the device Javascript also has a built-in `TextEncoder` class which can do the opposite and produce an `ArrayBuffer` filled with UTF-8, which should be interpreted correctly by the device.

Try this implementation of `bluetoothSend()` instead:

```js
function bluetoothSend(text) {
    log("You> " + text);
    myCharacteristic.writeValue(new TextEncoder().encode(text+"\n"))
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It solved my issue. The Arduino is now recieving data correctly. But I still have an issue with the keyboard library. Since I use a German keyboard, some chars are not printed properly. Does anyone have any glue how to solve that?

Comment: I recommend asking that as a separate question.